# error java The method combinationSum(int[], int, List<Integer>) in the type Solution is not applicable for the arguments (int[], int, boolean)

Tags: java

///**to get all values that addup to the target . error The method combinationSum(int[], int, List) in the type Solution is not 
     applicable for the arguments (int[], int, boolean)**

```
import java.util.*;
public class Solution {

    static List<Integer> b= new ArrayList<Integer>();
    static List<List<Integer>> c= new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
    public static void combinationSum(int[] candidates, int target, List<Integer> b) 
    {   
        if(target==0)
        {
            c.add(b);
        }

        else {
        for(int i=0;i<candidates.length;i++)
        {   

//          else
//          {
          //  if( target < 0 )
          //  {
                //b.remove( b.size() - 1 );
          //  }
            if(target>0)
            {
                //b.add(candidates[i]);
                combinationSum(candidates,target-candidates[i],b.add(candidates[i]));
                //b.remove( b.size() - 1 );
            }
            //}
        }
        }
        //return;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {   
        int[] candidates= {2,3,5};
        int target=8;
        combinationSum(candidates,target,b);
        System.out.println(c);
    }
```

Comment: I'd double check the javadoc, ArrayList.add(E e) returns a boolean. It's in your recursive call.

Comment: i need to add new value with each recursive caall

Answer (score 1):

You can try this :

```
b.add(candidates[i]);
combinationSum(candidates,target-candidates[i],b));
```

First add the candidates to `b` and then pass the list in the recursive call.